# Why is this code stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Why is `head` is going to some random value?

```
// Simple insertion at the starting of link list  

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int d;
    node *next;
}; // creation of node

node *head=new node; // is there any problem?

void insert(int x)
{
    if (head==NULL) { // is there something wrong?
        head->d=x;
        haad->next=NULL;
    } else {
        node *t=new node;
        t->d=x;
        t->next=head;
        head=t;
    }
}

int main() {
    insert(1);           // function calling
    insert(2);           // function calling
    insert(3);           // function calling
    while(head!=NULL) {
        cout<<head->d<<" ";
        head=head->next;
    } // this is going on to infinity
    return 0;
}
```

This code is lopping till infinity and I am not able to understand why?
Why is `head` going to some random value after 3 2 1? Is there any problem in declaring head globally?

Comment: You should add the programming language to the tags.

Comment: Improved formatting, grammar and title.

Comment: cout ==> C++ I assume

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 2):

`head` is going to some random value because the last element in your list is pointing with `next` to a random value.

This last element is the first node you created in this line:

```
node *head=new node;
```

By doing that, you are allocating memory for this node on the heap, however, you're not setting any values to the node's fields, including `next`. Then in the loop, when `head` is pointing to the last node (that was allocated first) `head->next` is not `NULL` and therefore the loop continues.

---

Three side notes:

1. Using `head` itself to iterate over the list elements is not a good idea since you're losing the pointer to the head of the list.
2. `head` can be declared globally but usually you should have a good reason for that. In your program I'd define it in `main()` and pass it to the functions that need it.
3. This code:

   ```
   if (head==NULL) { // is there something wrong?
       head->d=x;
       haad->next=NULL;
   ```

   doesn't make lots of sense: it will never run, and in case it will --> segmentation fault (because if `head` is `NULL` you cannot refer to its fields.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understand your point. node *head=new node; does not initialize head as null. Thanks